# Get User Interface on Qt rescaled: how?

Tags: qt, user-interface

I've made an app that work ok for everyone except a fixed user, he has a 2560 x 1440 screen (but we already tried on other screen with the same resolution).

The issue is that everything is so much bigger than expected including widgets thare are set to work on a fixed size given in pixels.

I know that I've provided really few info but to be honest I cannot imagine any other relevant information since this is everything I know.

Any tip is welcome.
Regards!

PS. this scale is afecting everything including fonts, images etc.

Answer (score 4):

It's a Windows feature - the screen DPI has been changed to make the UI more readable. Your application must cope with it, that's what layouts are for. Had you used layouts, or even a custom layout manager, it'd have worked. Your design is fundamentally deficient and it has to be addressed.

Fixed position layouts are bad not only because modifying them is labor intensive, but also because they never work when common accessibility and translations are enabled.

Comment: No, I'm not using fixed position in most of the parts but some icons etc.
Also inside layouts the widgets are scaled ok but the content (images) are too big and they are cropped inside the widget.

Comment: @FrankEscobar You can't have "some" fixed position and some not. Either it all adjusts to the real element size, or it doesn't. There's no middle ground. The icons etc. are **meant to be bigger** - that's why the user has changed their DPI. If they don't want that, they can change the DPI back. It's not only your application that looks big, after all.

Comment: No the actual problem is that only my application suffers this problem the rest of apps and windows of the SO looks normal.

Answer (score 2):

All from the below answer of mine is applicable here: [Qt5.6: high DPI support and OpenGL (OpenSceneGraph)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37303941/qt5-6-high-dpi-support-and-opengl-openscenegraph/37304973#37304973)

*P.S. I am not to argue with Kuba Ober's answer, the problem is very familiar to me and in addition to all the proper layouts etc. something needs to be done, specifically: activating DPI Awareness which is a bit 'undiscovered' topic for Qt on Windows. There are great improvements starting Qt 5.6 and that requires introducing the proper manifest to executable etc. I for now use a shortcut with Qt 5.5 as described in my previous answer.*